# Five close-voters. One is moderator. So, he wasn't at the time?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, closed-questions, moderators

There is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8056207/6044352) that was closed by five people. The first to cast a close-vote is a diamond moderator.

My understanding is that if he had been a diamond moderator at the time of casting that vote, the question would have been closed instantly, and only he would have been listed as the closer.

Therefore, I assume he was made a moderator *after* casting that close-vote.

Even if that is indeed the case for this particular question, would there be any other technically possible reason for that?

"That" meaning: Five close-voters are listed and one of them (except for the last) has a diamond next to his name.

Comment: In fairness, the question in the link was closed Nov 30 '11. So I don't get the interest/curiosity factor, I mean "so what"?

Comment: @Mari-LouA I already told you I was curious, right? I just like to know how SE works :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A moderator's close vote is always binding if that user is a moderator when the vote is cast. The diamond always appears next to a moderator's name, even if the user was not a moderator at the time of closing/posting/editing/whatever. Therefore, it is as you suspected: a moderator appearing as a non-binding closer was not a mod at the time.

Note that the [moderators tab of the users page](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) shows when each mod was elected/appointed, and you can click through to see exactly when the election finished, if you're curious.